# different position of views on android device compared to designer screen with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, view

i'm just new at developing app for android device, with xamarin.

My issue is that i have a different position of my views (Min and max) when it's on my device compared to the designer screen. The other views are in the right places.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputMin"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="Min"
    android:textColor="#EF5350"
    android:textColorHint="#EF5350"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="5" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputMax"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inputMin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="Max"
    android:textColor="#EF5350"
    android:textColorHint="#EF5350"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputMin"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="5" />
```

how can i fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Regards, Sam.

Comment: Normally when we are using certain layout params like `layout_below` or `layout_toRightOf`,we don't add `+` for existing id. ex:`android:layout_below="@id/title"`. If the problem is not fixed by this, could you please post the whole xml codes?

Comment: it didn't work. I just posted the whole xml code. I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="#F44336"
    android:text="Random Number"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputMin"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="Min"
    android:textColor="#EF5350"
    android:textColorHint="#EF5350"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="5" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputMax"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/inputMin"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:hint="Max"
    android:textColor="#EF5350"
    android:textColorHint="#EF5350"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inputMin"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="5" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/generate"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputMin"
    android:text="Generate"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#F44336"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:clickable="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultat"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/generate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#F44336"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```